# How to show that ols doesn't do well on high correlated predictors

Tags: multiple-regression

I have here an R example with highly correlated predictors. How can I show that OLS doesn't predict well on highly correlated predictors?

```
#OLS highly correlated 
set.seed(18814)
n = 50
p = 20
real_p=10
CovMatrix <- outer(1:20, 1:20, function(x,y) {.9^abs(x-y)})
x=mvrnorm(n, rep(0,p), CovMatrix)
y <- apply(x[,1:real_p], 1, sum) + rnorm(n)
lm_fit=lm(y~x)
summary(lm_fit)
```

Should I apply this linear model fit onto a new dataset and see how it predicts? If yes how can I fit `lm_fit` onto a new dataset?

Update: When I do a summary of the model I get this:

```
Residual standard error: 1.168 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.99, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9831 
F-statistic: 143.7 on 20 and 29 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

If then I write the same code but where there is no correlation: `CovMatrix <- outer(1:20, 1:20, function(x,y) {0^abs(x-y)})`

I do a summary and get this:

```
Residual standard error: 1.168 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9173,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8602 
F-statistic: 16.08 on 20 and 29 DF,  p-value: 1.015e-10
```

Which value shows me that OLS performs worse in highly correlated settings. The R-square is higher in the correlated case which means that is better than the uncorrelated one.

Comment: Yes, I agree that you should fit your model to a new dataset. However, with highly correlated predictors, the main problem is that the coefficients related to each one are not very reliable, because you can't distinguish among the effects of the different predictors (multicollinearity increases standard errors). If predictors are equally correlated in the new dataset, I don't think you would necessarily have a low predictive power.

Comment: @FedericoTedeschi Is there any way to show that the standard error increases? Any example in R?

Comment: You don't really need an example to show this if you look at the formula for the variance-covariance matrix for the two predictor case where the predictors are highly correlated.

Comment: @FrankHarrell well I have to find a way to show that OLS doesn't predict well on highly correlated predictors. I don't know how to show this

Comment: @Ville Consider this: if the standard error of the regressors is high, then the confidence intervals for the predictions are high, that means that the model validation $R^2$ will be low. Does that make sense to you? Frank is right, you can just show the variance of the regressors is high and be done with it.

Comment: @AdamO Your argument implicitly assumes the variances of the regressor estimates are uncorrelated.  That's not the case when the variables are correlated.  In fact, the confidence intervals for the prediction can be essentially *zero* (and $R^2$ can be essentially $1$) while the standard errors of the regressors are arbitrarily large.  As a result, your argument is wrong and its conclusion is incorrect.

Comment: @Ville You can take a look here: http://www.statisticshowto.com/variance-inflation-factor/ You can see that, the higher the correlation of your predictor with the other ones, the higher the $R^2$ ($\rightarrow$ the lower the denominator) $\rightarrow$ the higher the Variance Inflation Factor

Comment: Highly correlated predictors present no problems in getting predictions, except in the special case where the co-linearities are different in new data than they were in old data.  For example, if two predictors were highly correlated in the model development data and x1=0, x2=1 was very unlikely to occur, an observation with x1=0, x2=1 in new data could give rise to a "wild" predicted value.